# Multiple Value Fields using the Google Chart Tools module

Tags: charts

I have a content type with 3 fields: date, planned, actual. Each field can have unlimited values. I am using the [Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) module and grouping on date.

What I want is the x-axis to have each date in the field. The y-axis would have the planned and actual data points relative to the date. Example, first date has first planned and actual values and so on.

The problem I am having is that the chart is adding all the values of the field resulting in two horizontal lines between the dates.

All of the fields have '`Display all values in the same row`' unchecked.

This seems straight forward, what are the correct settings to accomplish this?  Or is there a better approach?